# Jquery replace strange behaviour in action form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to create a modal popup that contains a confirmation delete button when I press delete on my index view, that button contains the ID of the object you are going to delete, I get it with jquery and replace the form action with it.
My problem is replace it not just replacing the placeholder ID on my action form, its replacing whole route with something like http://localhost/project/public/logout.

Delete button on my index.blade.php:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="{{$category->id}}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>
```

Form on modal:

```
<form action="{{route('categories.destroy', ['id' => 'placeHolderId'])}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          @method('DELETE')
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
```

Jquery function that replaces the placeholderId on form action attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#deleteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var placeHolderId = button.data('id'); 

        var modal = $(this);
        var action = $('form').attr('action');
        modal.find('form').attr("action", action.replace('placeHolderId', placeHolderId));
    });
});
```

Result:

```
<form action="http://localhost/project/public/logout" method="POST">
```

Expected result:

```
<form action="http://localhost/project/public/manager/categories/1" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the submit form another id, and on jQuery find the form by that Id, cause right now, its gettign the first form on the DOM and thats logout form

basically put id="categoriesForm" and on jQuery $("#categoriesForm").submit()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#deleteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var placeHolderId = button.data('id'); 

        var modal = $(this);
        var action = $('#categoryForm').attr('action');
        modal.find('#categoryForm').attr("action", action.replace('placeHolderId', placeHolderId));
    });
});
```

or what you can do, is capture when the form is submit, then prevent the default, do the confirmation pop up and then submit

```
<form action="{{route('categories.destroy', ['id' => 'placeHolderId'])}}" method="POST" id="categoryForm">
      @csrf
      @method('DELETE')
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#categoryForm").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this category!");

        if(confirmDelete) {
            $(this).submit()
        }
    })
});
```